# I can't get information with bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying scrape the title, contact information (phone) and webpage from this url:

```
https://partnerportal.fortinet.com/directory/search?l=Spain&p=1
```

`&p=1` —This is the page. There are 92.

This is my code. I cannot get anything in the print output.

```
import datetime

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

filename = "fichero" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+".csv"
with open(filename, "w+") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Nombre Empresa", "Direccion Empresa", "Telefono Empresa"])

    for i in range(1,3):
        r = requests.get('https://partnerportal.fortinet.com/directory/search?l=Spain&p='+format(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        array_title = soup.select('div.panel panel-default div.col-sm-10 h3')
        array_address = soup.select('div.panel panel-default p.locator-partner-info')
        array_webpage = soup.find_all('a', class_='locator-parter-site', text=True)
        for iterator in range(0, len(array_title)):
           title = array_title[iterator].text.strip()
        for iterator2 in range(0, len(array_address)):
            address = array_address[iterator2].text.strip()
            print(title)
            print(address)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
array_title = soup.select('div.panel panel-default div.col-sm-10 h3')
array_address = soup.select('div.panel panel-default p.locator-partner-info')
```

Try This

```
array_title = soup.select('div.panel-default div.col-sm-10 h3')
array_address = soup.select('div.panel-default p.locator-partner-info')
```

and you are printing title in address loop which prints only the last assigned value i.e., Tiws. Better print in title loop only to see the correct result.

Comment: but with this first show the title and later the address, not show title and address ej NTT SPAIN CALLE PUJADES... show all titles and after this all address

Comment: for iterator in range(0, len(array_title)):


        title.append(array_title[iterator].text.strip())

        address.append(array_address[iterator*2].text.strip())

        specialization.append(array_address[(iterator*2)+1].text.strip())

Comment: Use the above loop instead of those 2 for loops

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from the website:

```
url = "https://partnerportal.fortinet.com/directory/search?l=Spain&p=1"
html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
rows = html.find('div', {'class':'row row-results'})
results = [{
    'id': row.find('div', {'class':'col-sm-10'})\
        .find('h3').getText(),
    'phone':row.find('div', {'class':'partner-info-box'})\
        .find('p').getText().split('Phone: ')[1].split('\n')[0],
    'url': row.find('div', {'class':'partner-info-box'})\
        .find('a').get('href')
} for row in html.find('div', {'class':'row row-results'})\
    .find_all('div', {'class':'col-sm-12'})]
```

In order to save the `.json` to `.csv`

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime 

filename = "fichero" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+".csv"
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results).to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: This work, but how can pass the results to one csv?

Comment: I am trying to do it, but for some reason, the information that is entered in the csv is partial, also for example I am trying to get the address and it is not possible, all the time I get \r

I do not understand what I am doing wrong, I must read much more             'address': row.find('div', {'class': 'partner-info-box'}).find('p').getText()[0] ( ej this is the code for get the address but i get the \r)

Comment: And another thing, this is for multiple page thats why i have one for, when it loops through it for some reason, it shreds the previous csv content, i don't know how to keep it in the file